# Creating Message System using UNION in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I m trying to create message system where I want to show list of users to whom I sent message or I receive a message.So that I can have list of users with whom I interacted 
Here is my message table structure

```
msgID   sentBy  sentTo  message     sentTime 
1         3     1       Hii B      1493306882
2         3     1       Hi A       1493309615
1         1     3       Hmm        1493306882
2         1     3       Yeah       1493309615
```

and the query i tried is

```
(SELECT * FROM user_message LEFT JOIN users ON user_message.sentTo=users.userID
WHERE user_message.sentBy='".$_SESSION['userid']."' GROUP BY sentTo) UNION

(SELECT * FROM user_message LEFT JOIN users ON user_message.sentBy=users.userID 
WHERE user_message.sentTo='".$_SESSION['userid']."' GROUP BY sentBy)
```

**PROBLEM**: Using the above query it shows users name the amount of time I send msg or receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your individual select queries are selecting all columns, while only grouping by one column. You can correct this by only selecting the columns that you actually want, and adding those columns to your group clause.

In addition, you can add `distinct` to your union, in order to return a distinct set of results from both returned tables. Additionally, you could use `distinct` in your select queries rather than group, but that's another discussion.

Assuming that your query is already doing what you need it to do, you can make a small change to the field(s) you're selecting and what field(s) you're grouping. I also tossed in the `union distinct`.

```
(SELECT users.userName FROM user_message LEFT JOIN users ON user_message.sentTo=users.userID
WHERE user_message.sentBy='".$_SESSION['userid']."' GROUP BY users.userName) 

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT users.userName FROM user_message LEFT JOIN users ON user_message.sentBy=users.userID 
WHERE user_message.sentTo='".$_SESSION['userid']."' GROUP BY users.userName)
```

On a side note, I see that you're putting $_SESSION['userid'] directly into your query. Make sure this variable is properly sanitized against sql injections!

Comment: And what if I want sentTime column as well with the userName ?

Comment: And also How can i ORDER the users By DESC ?

Comment: Because both your subqueries are parenthesied, you can simply add the `order` clause to the end of the query.
See MySQL's UNION documentation for more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: As for the sentTime column, you can simply add `max(sentTime) as lastSentTime` to both of your select statements, in order to see the latest sentTime. However, I should mention that this will mess up the `union distinct` because the "sent" and the "recieved" queries will have two different lastSentTime values, and would be considered distinct.

Comment: I just changed my whole UNION query to LEFT JOIN all 3 tables